# Rails - How to write a sum of two model attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sum

I'm trying to make an app with Rails 4.

I have 3 models.

```
Project.rb
ProjectInvitation.rb
ProjectStudentEoi.rb
```

The associations are:

```
Project has may project_invitations
Project has many project_student_eois

ProjectInvitation belongs to project
ProjectStudentEoi belongs to project
```

I'm trying to count how many students are participating in a project. They can either be invited or express interest (if not invited).

In my project.rb, I tried to write a method to sum the count of accepted invitations or approved expressions of interest.

In project.rb, I have:

```
  def self.students_participating

       ProjectStudentEoi.interested_students.sum.
ProjectInvitation.invitations_accepted
  end
```

Note: I only split the above line into two lines because SO won't indent this long a line. It's all one continuous line in my code.

In my projectInvitation.rb I have:

```
def self.invitations_accepted
    @project.project_invitations.where(student_accepted: true)
  end
```

In my ProjectStudentEoi.rb, I have:

```
    def self.interested_students
        @project.project_student_eoi.where
(creator_accepted: true).count
    end
```

Again, the above code is split in 2 lines in this post because SO won't indent it as code when its this long.

Then in my projects view folder, I have a partial, which has:

```
<%= @project.students_participating %> students participating 

NoMethodError at /projects/2
undefined method `students_participating' for #<Project:0x007ff733333830>
```

How do you write a sum of two count methods in rails?

I tried the example given in the answer below - so in my Project.rb:

```
def students_participating
   project_student_eois.interested_students.sum + 
   project_invitations.invitations_accepted
  end
```

I get this error:

```
NoMethodError at /projects/2
undefined method `interested_students' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

Picking up on Meier's suggestions below, I tried to rewrite my class methods as scopes, so in ProjectStudentEoi.rb, I have:

```
  scope :creator_accepted, lambda { where(creator_accepted: true)}
```

In ProjectInvitation.rb I have

```
scope :student_accepted, lambda { where(student_accepted: true)}
```

Then in project.rb (adapting Meier's suggestion), I have:

```
def students_participating

    project_student_eois.creator_accepted.count + 
    project_invitations.students_accepted.count
  end
```

I don't have a count function in the child objects any more.

When i try this, I get this error:

```
NoMethodError at /projects/2
undefined method `creator_accepted' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

THEN - taking Meier's revised suggestion, I tried:

```
 def students_participating

    project_student_eois.creator_accepted + 
    project_invitations.students_accepted.count
  end
```

I get this error:

```
NoMethodError at /projects/2
undefined method `creator_accepted' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want a number, and not a list of objects. So you break the scope chain. Instead your method should be just an instance method. Because of this, you can simply call the relations of your project object. And lastly we have the `+` to calculate the sum of two numbers :-)

```
class Project
  ....
  def students_participating
    project_student_eois.interested_students + 
      project_invitations.invitations_accepted.count
  end
```

You should also read [Rails guides about scopes](http://file:///home/meier/rails/inspect1/doc/guides/active_record_querying.html#scopes) here. scopes can be expressed as class methods, and you have done that. That is ok, but you need to know when to do it, and when to use normal instance methods.

Comment: so i don't need the count methods is the two child objects?

Comment: Hi Meier, I tried this but it didn't work. Are you sure I don't need to do the count somewhere first?

Comment: so interested_students is already counting. invitations_accepted is not counting, you we need to append a count to this.

Comment: I tried it  & get this 
undefined method `interested_students' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>

Comment: Maybe it is better that interested_students is not counting.it looks better if just get all the interested students (do be precise: the scope with the interested students) and then the count is done explicitly.

Comment: are you sure you don't need something in the project model to point to the child models (with an '@')?

Comment: Wait - do you mean I need to define a scope somewhere? I haven't done that.

Comment: Oh, you have done it. You're class methods are scopes. I suggest to read about it in the rails guide.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, I have re written them as scopes above. No idea what the rails guide has in it for sums. I've spent the morning trawling for ideas about how to do this.

Comment: I tried the revised suggestion and posted the error above. Thanks anyway -